How to set collision bit mask to `all` in SceneKit in Swift
I need to set a SCNNode's collisionBitMask to the default value, which is all bit set.
It turns out to be pretty tricky, and the following is my research so far:
collisionBitMask is an Int type (not UInt)!

The default value is all (a bit mask whose every bit is enabled), specifying that the body will collide with bodies of all other categories.

Then clicking into the link, we have:

static var all: SCNPhysicsCollisionCategory { get }

From SCNPhysicsCollisionCategory's doc, we know the rawValue is a UInt.
i can't direct cast UInt to Int since I will lose precision:
toyUI.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Int(SCNPhysicsCollisionCategory.all.rawValue)
I got this error:

Swift/Integers.swift:3687: Fatal error: Not enough bits to represent the passed value


Try to set it like so:
toyUI.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Int.max

SCNPhysicsCollisionCategory.all.rawValue (as UInt) enables all 64 bits.
Int.max also sets all bits except the sign bit to 1, which is sufficient to represent the "all categories".

but they are still different value right? The default is Int.min?

One is signed the other is not. This difference belongs just to one bit (the first) in the sequence and is handled by the type definition. So from my understanding they are different. i.Ex. on signed Integers (Int), the sign bit determines if it is a positive or negative value. Range: -2^63 to +2^63 - 1 - the UInt (Unsigned) has the range: 0 to +2^64 - 1. It cannot be negative. You need to initialize the Int before you can use it. It has a declared default of 0, but which is not explicitly initialized. And Int.min defaults to: -9223372036854775808

why is the objc version unsigned? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicscollisioncategory?language=objc

I suspect this is some internal ObjC to Swift bridging magic there. What do you think @ZAY

Objective-C uses NSUInteger for bitmasks because it’s an unsigned type, aligning with Apple’s API conventions and avoiding negative values, which aren't meaningful for bitmasks. In Swift, Int is used because it’s the default integer type, offering simplicity and type safety. Swift’s strong typing makes unsigned integers less necessary, and Int interoperates seamlessly with Objective-C’s NSUInteger. In Swift, Int is signed, you can use -1 as a bitmask, which effectively sets all bits to 1 in two’s complement binary representation. This is useful for i.Ex a light to shine on everything.

hmmm, i suspect that's not the case. I think it's apple's mistake. In SpriteKit, the bit mask is in UInt32. : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519869-categorybitmask
